# image background change on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

i am trying to change background image on scroll, but cant seem to find any guide, so i will try my luck here.
here is a video of exactly what i am trying to achieve - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7u1aIxQCIXg
i want to have a background image, and text that goes over when i scroll, and when i come to a certain point, the background image changes/fades over and not scrolls up from the bottom

i have tried some, but does not have the skills at this point

Comment: We don't debug YouTube videos! [Edit] the question and create a textual [mcve]

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although you didnt provided any progress you made still i enjoyed making it
accept my answer if you find it usefull please check my codepen link
[demo](https://codepen.io/amir-rahman/full/rNwKzVG)

```
<style>
    body {margin: 0;padding: 0;}
    .section {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        z-index: 1;
        position: relative;
        background-size: 100% 100% !important;

    }
    .text {
        margin:auto;
        font-size: 2.5em;
        border:1px solid white; 
        color:white;
        padding:1em;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black,
                     2px 2px 3px black;        
    }
    .BG {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 0;
        opacity: 0.4;
        transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
    }
    .anim {opacity:1;}
    .show {color:orange;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="section BG">
        <div class="show"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.ibb.co/0DxzSg0/pngtree-blue-carbon-background-with-sport-style-and-golden-light-image-371487.jpg"><div class="text">SECTION</div></div>
    <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.ibb.co/31YPsfg/triangles-1430105-340.png"><div class="text">SECTION</div></div>
    <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.ibb.co/Y3BgqMc/7f3e186790208b63dadda09d6b91d334.jpg"><div class="text">SECTION</div></div>
    <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.ibb.co/GCQP61b/photo-1513151233558-d860c5398176-ixlib-rb-1-2.jpg"><div class="text">SECTION</div></div>
    <div class="section" BGurl="https://i.ibb.co/D9WGPf9/pngtree-modern-double-color-futuristic-neon-background-image-351866.jpg"><div class="text">SECTION</div></div>
</div>
</body>

<script>
    function scrollPictureChange(){
        var main = document.querySelector(".main"),
            sections = main.querySelectorAll(".section"),
            BG = main.querySelector(".BG"),
            el = document.querySelector(".show"),cords,index=0,h = window.innerHeight,lastIndex=null,offset=0

        applyBG(0)
        window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
            scrollY = Math.abs(document.body.getClientRects()[0].top)
            index = Math.floor(scrollY / (h - offset))

            if(index != lastIndex){ // on index change
                if(lastIndex != null){
                    applyBG(index)
                 }
                lastIndex = index
            }
            
            el.innerText = `index : ${index} height : ${h} top : ${scrollY}`
        })

        function applyBG(index){
            BG.classList.remove("anim")
            setTimeout(function(){
                BG.style.backgroundImage = `url(${sections[index + 1].getAttribute("BGurl")})`
                BG.classList.add("anim")
            },300)
        }            
    }

    window.onload = scrollPictureChange
    window.onresize = scrollPictureChange

</script>
```

Comment: Instead of posting a link to Codepen, consider using a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: @Felipe Saldanha its a `window.onscroll` based code and there is lots of other elements in this window so its breaking my code . i do used code snippet first it is breaking intended functionality then i edited and put it in codepen and added link here